# How can we remove the divider between the ActionBar and the tabs

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to remove the divider between the ActionBar and the tabs but I did not succeed yet. I've tried below code and i am getting result like my below image

can some one help me please how can i remove this line

### code:-

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabPatient"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Add your `tablayout` within the `appbarlayout` below `toolbar`

Comment: please explain with some code i am begginer in android

Comment: Check posts on stackoverflow about appbarlayout

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

and in your java code:

```
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

also you have to insert the dependencies in build.gradle file but if you don't know how to implement it ask me

Comment: how can i implement depedencies ?

Comment: add `   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'` to your build.gradle file in its dependency section

Comment: yes off-course i am using compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1' and   compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'

Comment: tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabPatient);
            viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
            tabLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
            tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#727272"), Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

Comment: in my java code i done nothing just added Color programatically

Comment: i saw that you didn't add toolbar in your updated xml code, you have to add it

Comment: According to my requirement ToolBar i have added on My Base Activity Xml file and This Tabs need to add on my child fragment xml file

Comment: i hope u understand

Answer (score 0):

replace your `tablayout` with this structure:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/p_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/bar_color"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabPatient"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    style="@style/Tab"
    app:tabTextAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

a more better option will be to use all of this in a `CoordinatorLayout` and then include your main layout in it...